# Error on views page. Any idea what this means?

Tags: 7, views

Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a
>   packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes: UPDATE
>   {sessions} SET uid=:db_update_placeholder_0,
>   cache=:db_update_placeholder_1, hostname=:db_update_placeholder_2,
>   session=:db_update_placeholder_3, timestamp=:db_update_placeholder_4
>   WHERE ( (sid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (ssid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_1) ); Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0]
>   => 1 [:db_update_placeholder_1] => 0 [:db_update_placeholder_2] => 173.8.158.117 [:db_update_placeholder_3] => Wpw4khR1syd0trFnNVSUxDsOs_MtPQ

That gibberish at the end beginning with `=&gt;` goes on for dozens of pages dumped directly onto the page. Any idea what to look into?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to bump up [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) in your MySQL instance.  That query is likey trying to store a large amount of data.  I have never seen this at runtime, though.  I have only had problems with this variable when trying to restore backups.

Comment: I'll try that, but I don't want to bandaid a larger problem. All the CCK fields the view is returning have really short string values. Where could the massive amount of data that's overflowing my packet size be coming from?

Comment: That particular query is trying to save off session data.  That could be anything.  The only way to debug this is to unserialize the data and see what is in it.

Comment: So paste the entire output into an unserialize function?

Comment: Just double checked this.  It is not exactly just serialized data.  You need to look at what is being put into the sessions.session column to see what I am talking about.

Comment: Hmm checked my DB and I have a couple session entries. They're both only ~30 or so characters long though.

Comment: That will show you the format of how the key/values are stored.  The error message is from a failed attempt to add to that table.  You need to debug that particular query to see what was being added to the session table.